# Can't get a true if conditional to trigger in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to stylize my different blog post tags by running an if conditional that simply checks for the name of the tag and executes the style I want for that specific tag. It appears the condition should check True, but only the code under the else clause is being executed.

In the example below, my "News" tag should have the class badge badge-primary, but instead it's falling under the else and applying badge badge-secondary.

I've tried upper and lower case. I've also tried with and without the counter, which is there for other purposes. Still, no luck.

Template:

```
{% for tag in object.tags.all %}
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}
{% if tag == "News" %}
<li>
<span class="badge badge-primary">{{ tag }}</span>
</li>
{% else %}
<li>
<span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ tag }}</span>
</li>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

When replacing:

```
{% if tag == "News"  %}
```

With:

```
{% if tag in object.tags.all %}
```

It works, and the tag will populate the first span class as it should. I believe this tells me that the syntax I'm using is correct. For some reason my == conditional isn't being seen True, even though it should be.

To check things further, I ran shell to ensure I'm using the correct tag names.

```
Tags.objects.all
```

Returned (leaving a few out for brevity):

```
<QuerySet [<Tags: Reviews>, <Tags: News>, <Tags: Tech>]>
```

Model:

```
class Tags(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='general')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm using generic DetailView for my view.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of {{ tag }} when it comes to badge-secondary?

Comment: "News" is displaying for badge-secondary. Somehow it's False on the initial conditional and executes the else block instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tag is an object when we iterate object.tags.all as invoking .all() will return a QuerySet that contains all Tag objects.

Instead, can you try tag.name == "News"

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now.